# Symmetric Algebra of a Graded Module

Tags: graded-rings, graded-modules, graded-algebras

Let $k$ be a commutative ring. Let $M$ be a $k$-module. Let $M$ be a graded module, concentrated in degree one. Then, the shifted module $M[1]$ is concentrated in degree zero. Hence, $M[1]$ is trivially graded or equivalently ungraded. The symmetric algebra of the ungraded module $M[1]$ is defined as

$$\mathrm{Sym}^{\bullet}(M[1]):=T^{\bullet}(M[1])/I,$$

where $I:=\langle x\otimes y- y\otimes x~|~x, y\in M[1]\rangle$.

What is the degree of $\mathrm{Sym}^{n}(M[1])$? Is it zero or is it $n$? If it is zero, doesn't this contradict *Bourbaki*'s Algebra $I$, according to which the symmetric algebra of a graded module is graded, too?

Comment: I believe $\text{Sym}^{\bullet}(M[1])$ is a graded algebra concentrated at degree $0$.

Comment: Then why are people calling $\mathrm{Sym}^n(E)$ of some ungraded module $E$ a degree $n$ component? How is a graded algebra concentrated in degree zero? This makes sense only if the algebra $\mathrm{Sym}^{\bullet}(E)$ were bigraded at the beginning.

Comment: It is concentrated at degree $0$ because $M[1]$ is concentrated at degree $0$ (let $x,y\in M[1]$ then $x\otimes y$ is also of degree $0$ in $T^{\bullet}(M[1])$). A graded algebra concentrated at degree $0$ is just an ordinary algebra. I don't understand your bigraded argument in this case?